# Run project dependencies commands from dockerfile

Tags: mysql, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a laravel project that requires:

- mysql database image
- mongo database image
- dependencies: npm, composer, gulp, bower

So I created a `docker-compose.yml` with 3 services:

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  db-mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=app_db"
      - "MYSQL_USER=db_user"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=nutella"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=choco" 
  db-mongo:
    image: mongo
  app:
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\svirl\Documents\workspace\app-web:/var/www/html/:rw
    build: app
    links:
      - db-mysql
      - db-mongo
    ports:
      - 32772:80
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql
      - db-mongo
```

Ok so for my app I have a build with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN apt-get update

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer install #*
RUN apt-get install npm
RUN npm install #*
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN bower install --allow-root
RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN gulp
```

But of course that some commands like those with `#*` won`t work because the VOLUME is not mounted and the files does not exists yet and the errors are thrown like:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
```

So what solutions exists for this case? In order that my project to run I need to run those commands on the container creation.

Comment: Hi! check this out https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/, it's the best example to dockerize app. It's just a node app but you can use it with other languages.
;)

Comment: As I said in other questions, copy your code inside the container is not exclusive than creating a volume with docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script with the commands (`composer install, npm install...`) and put that script as [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I tried with `ENTRYPOINT composer install && npm install && /bin/sh -c` but the container won't start anymore.

Comment: write a shell script, `COPY` that to the image, make it executable and than set `ENTRYPOINT /path/to/script.sh`.

Comment: Also, please give more detail. Any error messages? What does `docker logs ` and `docker ps -a` say?